# Spring Boot Testing with embedded Postgressql database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mocking

I want to test my controller in Spring-Boot 2.1.3.
I want to simulate a POST request. 
This works quite well but I can't save the data to my Postgres database because H2 can't do JSONB. 
Therefore I use [this](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded) library to embed Postgres.

That works quiet well, the database starts but I can't/know how I can bring my mock to save the data in the embedded database.

Do you have any ideas ?

My Test:

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class ControllerTest
{


@InjectMocks
private Student student;

@InjectMocks
private StudentInfo studentinfo;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;


@ClassRule
public static PreparedDbRule preparedDbRule = EmbeddedPostgresRules.preparedDatabase( FlywayPreparer.forClasspathLocation( "db/migration" ) );

@Test
public void test() throws Exception
{

    try(EmbeddedPostgres postgres = EmbeddedPostgres.builder.setPort(62239).start();
    Connection connection = postgres.getPostgresDatabase().getConnection()){

    String jsonString = "{"Student" : "name", "course" : "course1"}";

        this.mockMvc.perform( post( "/students" )
                .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                .content( jsonString) )
                .andDo( print() )
                .andExpect( status().is( 201 )
                );
    }catch( Exception  e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:62239/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
flyway.enabled=false
```

This is not a duplicate question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956743/embedded-postgres-for-spring-boot-tests), because in this question they used a [libary](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test) to solve the problem which is only available/compatible in Spring-Boot 1.4.0

> upports both Spring and Spring Boot frameworks
>   Supported versions are Spring 4.3.0+ and Spring Boot 1.4.0+

**Edit**
After some testing i found out that i should use an "application.properties" file for my Test. I also set the Port for the Database. 
But now my I get an random port although i set it with setPort(). I get an random port every start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedded Postgres for Spring Boot Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956743/embedded-postgres-for-spring-boot-tests)

Comment: in your code have double @InjectMocks, you need to add I guess private Student student as Mock annotation, in order to inject mocks to the InjectMocks, so remove it and try it again.